# Is it possible to change layout for first row in the listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using a `ListView` and a custom adapter (`FooAdapter`)

the `FooAdapter` sets the list view in the constructor like this:

```
public FooAdapter(Context context, List<Foo> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item_foo, list);
    this.list = list;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

All that is working fine

**Question**

For the first row of the `ListView` I want to change the design of the row. Is that possible? Here is a mockup of what I'm envisioning.

[image]

Comment: Why not use a header view instead?

Comment: Because then when I scroll the list view the header will stick there. What I want is to have the first row scroll up as well...similr to how a list view scrolls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a header to the ListView like this:

```
View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

The header will scroll with the content.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can modify just the view for the first element by overriding the method getView from the BaseAdapter class as follows:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
if (position == 1) {
    // do some view processing
    return View;
} else {
    // do some other view processing
    return thisView;
}
```